# Problem with adding vector to symbolic function (for NDSolve)

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I'm trying to set up a system of differential equations for passing to NDSolve. Note that my initial conditions are vector valued so Mathematica *should* know that `raptor[[i]]` is a vector valued function. However, Mathematica seems to think that that `raptor[[i]]` is a scalar valued function (this is indicated by my output, which is included below).

Input:

```
human[\[Theta]_, t_] := 0 t*{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]} + {0, 10 Sin[\[Pi]/3]}

V = {25, 10, 25};
P = {{-10, 0}, {0, 20 Sin[\[Pi]/3]}, {10, 0}};
\[Theta] = 0;

 Flatten[
  Table[
  {
   raptor[[i]]'[t] == Normalize[human[\[Theta], t] - raptor[[i]][t]]
   raptor[[i]][0] == P[[i]]
  }, {i, 3}]
 ]
```

Output:

```
{ Raptor[[1]]'[t]=={ first component of human - raptor[[i]][t],
                     second component of human - raptor[[i]][t]},
  Raptor[[1]][0] =={-10,0}, 
  Raptor[[2]]'[t]== ... 
}
```

Furthermore, changing the raptor indexes into subscripts does not change anything. When I try to use this system in NDSolve I get the error "Computed derivatives do not have dimensionality consistent with the
initial conditions."

After talking to my TA for the course, we got this to work by defining `human[theta, t]` as one of the differential equations. However, my TA didn't know why my code failed (it seemed very reasonable to both of us) and said I could ask the Mathematica stack exchange.

So, could anyone explain why my code fails? Namely, why does Mathematica think that `raptor[[i]]` is a scalar valued function even though its initial condition is clearly vector valued? Is there a better way to do this then putting `human[theta, t]` into the list of equations for NDSolve?

PS: for those wondering, this is solving a variant of problem #2 from http://xkcd.com/135/

Comment: If you don't consider the acceleration, [the bottom raptors will get you before you can take any advantage of the top raptor's broken leg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xes95.png). Sorry.

Comment: I don't think running in straight line is the best strategy. But well, it only ask to "maximize the time you stay alive", after that, ...

Comment: I presume you've looked up "pursuit curves"?

Comment: @Silvia I'm solving a straight line version of this for the course. To everyone else: I'm familiar with the solutions to this problem, I'm just curious as to why my Mathematica code doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should initialize `raptor` as something like `raptor = {raptor1, raptor2, raptor3}` before using `raptor[[i]]`.

Answer (score 3):

*The following example is written for **Mathematica 9**, and will NOT be compatible with previous versions.*

According to your question, this looks like some kind of homework, so I'd show a slightly different example, just to demonstrate how to index variables (by one of many possible ways), and how to use some features of `NDSolve` that may be helpful for chasing problems.

So here we have a target initially at $(0, 0)$, and some chasers distribute uniformly on a circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $10$:

```
Clear[targetPos]
targetPos[v_, θ_, t_] := v t*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}

chaserNumber = 6;

chaserOrigPos = 
  10 {Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2 π - (2 π)/chaserNumber, (2 π)/chaserNumber];
```

Then we define the ODE system. Please notice how `chaserPos` is indexed. For something like $f_{i,j}(x)$, instead of using `f[[i,j]][x]` or even `Subscript[f,i,j][x]`, `f[i][j][x]` might be a more convenient choice (you don't need to initialize it and don't have upper/lower limits for indices):

```
Clear[eqsys]
eqsys[chaserVelocity_, targetVelocity_, θ_] := Flatten[Table[{
    Derivative[1][chaserPos[i][j]][
      t] == ((chaserVelocity #)/Sqrt[#.#] &)[
       targetPos[targetVelocity, θ, t] - Through[(chaserPos[i] /@ {1, 2})[t]]
       ][[j]],
    chaserPos[i][j][0] == chaserOrigPos[[i, j]]
    },
   {i, chaserNumber}, {j, 2}]]
```

Now the system is ready for `NDSolve`. Please note how `WhenEvent` stops the integration when any chaser is close enough ($\text{distance}<0.1$) to the target:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{sol, tmax = 20},
  sol = With[{stopCondition = Or @@ (
        Norm[
            targetPos[targetVelocity, θ, t] - Through[(chaserPos[#] /@ {1, 2})[t]]
            ] < .1 & /@
         Range[chaserNumber])},

    NDSolve[{eqsys[chaserVelocity, targetVelocity, θ],
       WhenEvent[stopCondition, tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]
       } // Flatten,
     Flatten[
      Outer[chaserPos[#1][#2][#3] &, 
       Range[chaserNumber], {1, 2}, {t}]],
     {t, 0, tmax}]
    ];

  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Append[
       Through[(chaserPos[#] /@ {1, 2})[t]] & /@ 
         Range[chaserNumber] /. sol[[1]],
       human[targetVelocity, θ, t]
       ]], {t, 0, tmax},
     Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 400,
     Prolog -> {GrayLevel[.9], Polygon[chaserOrigPos]}
     ] /. Line[pts_] :> Arrow[pts] // Column[{tmax, #}] &
  ],

 {{θ, π/chaserNumber}, 0, (2 π)/chaserNumber},
 {{chaserVelocity, 10}, 0, 10},
 {{targetVelocity, 6}, 0, 10},
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image: chasing trail]

And we can plot the survival time for different escaping directions:

```
With[{chaserVelocity = 10, targetVelocity = 9.5},
 tmaxLst = {};
  Table[
  Module[{tmax = 20},
   With[{stopCondition = Or @@ (
        Norm[
            targetPos[targetVelocity, θ, t] - Through[(chaserPos[#] /@ {1, 2})[t]]
            ] < .1 & /@
         Range[chaserNumber])},

    NDSolve[{eqsys[chaserVelocity, targetVelocity, θ],
       WhenEvent[stopCondition, tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]
       } // Flatten,
     Flatten[
      Outer[chaserPos[#1][#2][#3] &, 
       Range[chaserNumber], {1, 2}, {t}]],
     {t, 0, tmax}];

    AppendTo[tmaxLst, {θ, tmax}]
    ]],
  {θ, Rescale[Range[0, 1, .01], {0, 1}, {0, (2 π)/chaserNumber}]}];

 ListPolarPlot[tmaxLst,
  Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Lighter[Red, .5],
  Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red,
  Epilog -> {Gray,
    Line[{{0, 0}, Max[tmaxLst[[All, 2]]] {Cos[#], Sin[#]}}] & /@
     Rescale[Range[0, 1, 1/8], {0, 1}, {0, (2 π)/chaserNumber}],
    Circle[{0, 0}, #, {0, (2 π)/chaserNumber}] & /@
     FindDivisions[{0, Max[tmaxLst[[All, 2]]]}, 20]
    }]     ]
```

[image: survival time curve]

Answer (score 1):

> could anyone explain why my code fails? Namely, why does Mathematica
>   think that raptor[[i]] is a scalar valued function even though its
>   initial condition is clearly vector valued.

`raptor[[i]]` is a scalar valued element of something which you wish to be a vector valued object. You haven't told Mathematica that it is a vector. Whenever you call something which you wish to index in this way you must initialise it first.

As @Silvia mentioned in the comments, you should initialise `raptor` to be a list. Then you can call its elements by index `i`.